# Does jmxremote affect tomcat performance?

Tags: monitoring, tomcat, munin, jmx

I'd like to enable jmxremote to monitor Apache Tomcat resources utilization with Munin, but I want to know if this will affect the servers performance, is so, how much will it be impacted.

Answer (score 2):

We monitor CPU usage on our servers(via SNMP) and when we enabled jmxremote to collect stats we did not see a noticeable appreciation in usage(real machines).  It looks like someone actually grabbed stats from this and documented it:

https://community.oracle.com/blogs/emcmanus/2006/07/21/how-much-does-it-cost-monitor-app-jconsole

They basically say it can vary based on app but saw as high as 5-6% cpu usage increase in some cases.